# Basic questions about stacks 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

I have [again](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58428/basic-questions-about-stacks) three basic questions about stacks.

1) When we consider categories fibered in groupoids, do we always mean *small* or *essentially* small groupoids? Especially I want to know if algebraic geometers always impose this condition when they talk about categories fibered in groupoids, especially stacks.

2) In the proof of Artin's criterion for algebraic spaces/stacks $X/S$ for every point $p \in X$ of finite type over $S$ a "local approximation" $X_p$ is constructed. Then $X = \coprod_p X_p$ does the job. But in order to show that this is actually a scheme in the given universe, we need that the points of finite type constitute a *set*. Perhaps I'm overlooking something trivial here, but I cannot see how we can use Artin's criterions to deduce this.

3) What is the current status of the book "[Algebraic Stacks](http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?pr_vo_det&key1=1287&key2=580&no_cache=1)" by Kai Behrend, Brian Conrad, Dan Edidin, William Fulton, Barbara Fantechi, Lothar Göttsche und Andrew Kresch? I would *love* to read it as soon as it is completed.

Comment: Regarding 1), the definition of a fibred category does not assume that the fibres are small, but in geometric examples they are (or at least are essentially small). For example, would you consider the groupoid of G-bundles on a fixed topological space to be a set? This groupoid is certainly essentially small once you have a classifying space BG.

Comment: Me again. The category GBund(X) of principal G-bundles on a fixed object X in a site (S,J) is equivalent to the hom-category Gpd_ana(X,_B_G) in the bicategory of internal groupoids, anafunctors and transformations (without loss of generality, assume S is a superextensive site - see nLab for definition - which is true in all geometric situations). Here _B_G is the groupoid with one object and morphisms G, and we consider X as a groupoid with only trivial morphisms. GBund(X) is essentially small when the axiom 'WISC' holds for J, again see nLab. But 'morally', if not actually, the 2-category....

Comment: ...of stacks in groupoids on (S,J) is equivalent to the bicategory of groupoids, anafunctors and transformations in S. Roughly speaking, all fibres of a stack are representable in this bicategory, and so given WISC, one knows that the fibres are essentially small. Oh, I should mention that really this is only expected to hold for geometric stacks (presentable by some space/scheme/what-have-you), but I guess that that is the case you are most interested in.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding 3), Andrew Kresch just told me that they gave up on the project.

Comment: Oh no       :-(    

Comment: There is always the stack project which actively developed, available at http://math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/